# Need Help to code from tpl to twig file opencart 3.0.2.0

Tags: twig, opencart

Code which was ok in tpl file of lod version opencart 1.5

```
<?php $counter=0;$fb_var=0; foreach ($totals as $total) { ?>
<?php if($counter==0){ $fb_var=$total['value'];?>
<?php echo "</pre>";}$counter++;} ?>
```

Now i have used following code for twig file in view of opencart 3.0.2.0
but says fatal error for $ sign

```
counter0fb_var0 {% for total in totals %}
{% ifcounter is 0%} fb_vartotal.value
{{ "</pre>" }}{% endif %}{% $counter = $counter + 1 %}{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Variables need to start with a letter

Comment: how it should be in that case?

Comment: i think it should be like this as you suggested 
{% set counter=0 %}{% set fb_var=0 %} {% for total in totals %} 
{% if (counter == 0) %} {% set fb_var=total['value'] %}
{{ "</pre>" }}{% endif %}{% set counter = counter + 1 %}{% endfor %}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this instead:

```
{% set counter = 0 %}
{% set fb_var = 0 %} 
{% for total in totals %}
    {% if counter == 0 %}
        {% set fb_var = total.value %}
        {{ "</pre>" }}
    {% endif %}
    {% set counter = counter + 1 %}
{% endfor %}
```

Keep in mind:

- Variables in twig does not start with `$` or anything else. just type in the variable name.
- put any variable or statement inside `{{` and `}}` to print it out.
- use `{%` and `%}` at the beginning and end of your `if`, `for` and `block`s.

Comment: have a look here 
`{% set counter=0 %}{% set fb_var=0 %} {% for total in totals %} {% if (counter == 0) %} {% set fb_var=total['value'] %} {{ "</pre>" }}{% endif %}{% set counter = counter + 1 %}{% endfor %}`

Comment: please check updated answer. also please remove this comment and add those information to your question

Answer (score 0):

You can use these free resources:

1. http://openconverter.io/ - online converter
2. https://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=marketplace/extension/info&extension_id=29835 - Twig Manager (add .twig support for your Opencart 2.x)
3. https://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=marketplace/extension/info&extension_id=31589 - OpenCart Template Switcher.

Quote: This module, when enabled, causes OpenCart to automatically detect the correct template engine depending on a template file extension (e.g. '.tpl', '.twig', '.smarty' etc). Extensions and web themes can now use both PHP-templates and Twig-templates. This allows developers to easily port old OC 2.x web themes with PHP templates (*.tpl files) to the new OC 3.0.x releases.